# Spring boot security login always runs error without descrption

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Ahoy!

I have a little problem that I've been struggling with for almost 3 days. I looked up almost all the stackoverflow answers related to this question and answers but none of them helped me solve this.

I am trying to create a login-registration web application using Spring Boot Security using MySQL and Thymeleaf.

So far my registration is working pretty well. I've got problem with the login part. I've tested the inputs in my *UserServiceImpl* and I got no white spaces in my input so I think my input are OK.

I run into error always when I am trying to log in. "/login?error=true"

Below you can see my project structure.

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnN7f.png)

My Security Configuration:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
        @Autowired
        private UserService userService;
        
        @Bean
        public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }
        
        @Bean
        public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
            DaoAuthenticationProvider auth = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
            auth.setUserDetailsService(userService);
            auth.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
            return auth;
        }
        
        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
        }
    
        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
            web.ignoring().antMatchers("/favicon.ico", "/resources/**", "/error", "/static/**");
        }
    
        
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(
                     "/signup",
                     "/kereses",
                     "/szallas",
                     "/index",
                     "/",
                        "/js/**",
                        "/bootstrap/**",
                        "/fonts/**",
                        "/css/**",
                        "/img/**",
                        "/static/**",
                        "/resources/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable().formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/index", true)
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .clearAuthentication(true)
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
            .permitAll();
        }
    
    }
```

This is the UserServiceImpl:

```
    @Service
    public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{
    
        private UserRepository userRepository;
        
        @Autowired
        private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
        
        public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository) {
            super();
            this.userRepository = userRepository;
        }
    
        @Override
        public User save(UserRegistrationDto registrationDto) {
            User user = new User(registrationDto.getKeresztnev(), 
                    registrationDto.getVezeteknev(), registrationDto.getEmail(),
                    passwordEncoder.encode(registrationDto.getJelszo()), Arrays.asList(new Role("ROLE_USER")));
            
            return userRepository.save(user);
        }
    
        @Override
        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        
            User user = userRepository.findByEmail(username);
            
            if(user == null) {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Helytelen felhasználónév vagy jelszó.");
            }
            return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getEmail(), user.getJelszo(), mapRolesToAuthorities(user.getRoles()));       
        }
        
        private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> mapRolesToAuthorities(Collection<Role> roles){
            return roles.stream().map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
        
    }
```

This is my login.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <title>SmartHotel.com</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Az elérhető árú hotelek és szállások helye. Foglalj most!">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,300italic,400italic,700italic" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fonts/font-awesome.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fonts/simple-line-icons.min.css" type="text/css" crossorigin="anonymous">   
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.min.css" type="text/css" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/login.css" type="text/css" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand bg-light navigation-clean">
            <div class="container"><a th:href="@{/}" class="navbar-brand">SmartHotel.com</a><button data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggler" data-target="#navcol-1"></button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcol-1"><a class="btn btn-primary ml-auto" role="button" th:href="@{signup}">Regisztráció</a></div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="text-center h-100" style="background-color: white; background-size: cover;">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="text-center m-auto">
                    <!--LOGIN FORM TODO meghatarozni az actiont-->
                    <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
                    
                        <h1 class="">Bejelentkezés</h1>
                        <div>
                        
                        
                        
                        <!-- logout message -->
                        <div th:if="${param.logout}">
                            <div class="">Sikeresen kijelentkezés.</div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <label for ="username" class="sr-only"> Email</label>
                            <input type="text" class = "form-control" id ="username" name = "username" placeholder="Email" autofocus="autofocus">
                        
                        <label for="jelszo" class="sr-only">Jelszó</label> 
                            <input type="password" id="jelszo" name="jelszo" class="form-control" placeholder="Jelszó" autocomplete="on" />
                            
                        <input type="submit" name="login-submit" id="login-submit" value="Bejelentkezés" />
                        
                       <span>Nincs még fiókja?<a th:href="@{/signup}">Regisztráció</a></span>
                        <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">© 2020</p>
                        </div>
                      </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

In my controller I have only this code about login because as far as I know my authentication does the login post requests.

```
    @GetMapping("/login")
        public String login() {
            return "login";
        }
```

[debug log](https://file.io/Fwe7vrUcUbsn)

Thanks any help in advance!

Comment: What version of Spring Security are you using? Are you able to post the debug logs?

Comment: I am using v2.3.0. I've put the debug log at the end of my question. You can download the text file from file.io.

Comment: Your password field must be named `password` else it won't match and you are trying to login without a password. Or configure the alternative name in the `loginForm` element in your config.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you so much!!! you saved me.

Answer (score 0):

You should move this line

```
.anyRequest().authenticated()
```

To be after the line:

```
.logout()
```

Because the below line will match all request and ask for authentication

```
.anyRequest().authenticated()
```